# When would you want to create a new Managed Path?

Tags: site-collection, taxonomy, web-application

Could someone explain when or why I would want to generate a new managed path in a SharePoint Web Application?

Bismarck

Answer (score 4):

The advantage of multiple managed paths is it's a first piece of metadata you can have in your farm.  It helps break sites out into logical trees even thought they all reside in the same farm.  This becomes very beneficial if you organize your structure very flat (many site collection)

Based on the managed paths, you can have different SLAs for things like retention and such.

We have several managed paths

- ourdomain.com/calendars (for public folder migration)
- ourdomain.com/sites (team sites)
- ourdomain.com/cmte (committees)
- ourdomain.com/research (research sites)
- ourdomain.com/projects (projects)
- ourdomain.com/personal (My Sites)

Comment: In all but the smallest environment's I highly recommend that personal sites be separated from the collaboration content, but it is a good example of how to segment content based on managed paths.

Comment: Ya, we're feeling that pain and have planned to address it in our 2010 upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to the meta-data reason mentioned by @pirateeric, I also find it very useful for being able to optimize content sources and search scopes within the search system.

Comment: Very good point.

Answer (score 0):

Nice post. Here is the one more post explaining Managed path in Sharepoint

http://sureshpydi.blogspot.in/2013/03/share-point-managed-paths.html